# Is it okay to include many .js files to make my code look modular?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where almost all functions were using Ajax request. I have so many lines of js code. Is it a good practice to dissect my js codes and just include it in my page, for example:

```
<script src="../js_code_func_1.js"></script>
<script src="../js_code_func_2.js"></script>
<script src="../js_code_func_3.js"></script>
<script src="../js_code_func_4.js"></script>
<script src="../js_code_func_5.js"></script>
```

Will there be any bad performance effect if I do this?

Thanks! From a JavaScript noob..

Comment: Its better to use a single file

Comment: thanks for your response @thecodeparadox, but why it is better to use a single file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 different perspectives:

1. From the development perspective - each file should contain only the small particular part of functionality (some limited and complete application unit)
2. From the UX perspective - the less files - the better (because the more HTTP request you have - the longer user will wait until the page is rendered)

So the common solution is to split your application to as much files as best design practices require and join+minify them before deploy

Comment: a nice tactic is to take the first option then build a little deployment script that appends all the js together.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the situation where your page is going to be used. Each new `script` tag is one more `http-request`, so there will be some performance lost there.

If the scale of the application is large, splitting them up into a Model View Controller (or similar) pattern is pretty efficient for development.

You can always stitch them all together for deployment.